# Using Selenium to check a box in a menu made by javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

Doing a test automation using Selenium and Java.

There is a page which must be run with IE (and not Chrome).  I believe it also uses coldfusion.  Anyway, clicking on an arrow brings up a menu of check boxes.  However, this menu is not normal html but rather Java Script (see below).  This is only a portion of the javascript function.

I need to select an option.
Basically, there is no direct .  I print the page source, and try to do a (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input")) which returns 0 elements.  So I am not really sure how to select a box.

Using a lot of String manipulation I can find the index of the option (by looking for ellipsis;") and doing some replacements.  I can open the menu but now what?  One thing that was suggested was do do an action.sendKeys(Keys.ARROWDOWN) according to the option's position in the list, but the arrow down, instead of going down the items in the list, moves the scrollbar.

Has anyone else encountered something like this or have suggestions? (Perhaps something using javascript executor?)

```
<SCRIPT defer>

var strInnerHTML = '<div>';
strInnerHTML += '<form action="" onsubmit="return false;">';
strInnerHTML += '<span class="checkboxdropdown">';
strInnerHTML += '<input  type=\"checkbox\" id=\"_78\" name=\"cbusers\" 
value=\"78\"><label for=\"_78\" HIDEFOCUS=\"true\" style=\"white- 
space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis;\">Option 1</label><br> 
<input  type=\"checkbox\" id=\"_90\" name=\"cbusers\" value=\"90\"><label 
for=\"_90\" HIDEFOCUS=\"true\" style=\"white-space:nowrap; text- 
overflow:ellipsis;\">Option 2</label><br><input  
type=\"checkbox\" id=\"_139\" name=\"cbusers\" value=\"139\"><label 
for=\"_139\" HIDEFOCUS=\"true\" style=\"white-space:nowrap; text- 
overflow:ellipsis;\">Option 3</label><br>
```

Comment: Are you able to provide the actual site by any chance?

Comment: Sorry...it is inside out firewall.  I had to replace the actual option names with "Option 1", "Option 2", etc, in case any company secrets

Comment: You can easily use a javascript executor,  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: The click works, but not selecting the boxes.  I did try to javascript click the check box

Comment: inspect the menu after it's open... that'll have the markup... if you want to use keydown try switching to the active element first... "WebElement element = driver.switchTo().activeElement();        element.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);"

Comment: you can also use a WebDriverWait to wait for the input elements of type "checkbox" to be there.  Do this after the action that opens the menu.

Comment: I waited 50 seconds but still when I viewed the source all it showed was that strInnerHTML += stuff.  I think I will try the suggestion about activeElement() or maybe find a setFocus()?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, we have a section of the selenium library called "until", so there's probably something similar in Java.

In JS:

```js
(async ()=>{
    let element = driver.findElement({id: "example"});

    return await driver.wait(await until.elementIsVisible(element)).then(async ()=>{
        return await element.click();
    });    
})();
```

If you wait until the elements are displayed on the page before you start interacting with them, you'll probably have more luck.

Sorry that I couldn't help in Java though

Answer (score 0):

By name:

```
List<WebElement> checkbox = driver.findElements(By.name("cbusers"));
checkbox.get(0).click();
```

By cssSelector:

```
List<WebElement> checkbox = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
checkbox.get(0).click();
```

By tagName:

```
List<WebElement> checkbox = driver.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
checkbox.get(0).click();
```

With JavaScript:

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.name("cbusers"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkbox );
```

Comment: Yes I know how to find elements.  It is just that they are not there, or accessible by selenium, because they are created dynamically through javascript.  Or do you have to do something similar to switching to a Javascript iframe?